# "RouteReuseStrategy" and "LazyLoad" don't work after upgrading from Angular 12 to 13

Tags: routes, lazy-loading, upgrade, angular13, routereusestrategy

In Angular 12, "RouteReuseStrategy" works perfectly. However, after upgrading to Angular 13, "RouteReuseStrategy" stopped working. After careful examination, I noticed that the issue only occurs when components are loaded using "Lazy Load." When the same exercise is performed with components called directly, it works without any issues.

```
  handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {}

  // Decides if the route should be stored
  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return true;
  }

  // Store the information for the route we're destructing
  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    const URL = this.getFullUrl(route);
    this.handlers[URL] = handle;
  }

  // Return true if we have a stored route object for the next route
  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    const URL = this.getFullUrl(route);
    return !!this.handlers[URL];
  }

  // If we returned true in shouldAttach(), now return the actual route data for restoration
  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    const URL = this.getFullUrl(route);
    const COMPONENT: DetachedRouteHandle = this.handlers[URL];
    return COMPONENT ? COMPONENT : null;
  }

  // Reuse the route if we're going to and from the same route
  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.getFullUrl(curr) === this.getFullUrl(future);
  }

  private getFullUrl(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    const subRoutes: UrlSegment[] = [].concat.apply(
      [],
      route.pathFromRoot.map(subRoute => subRoute.url)
    );
    const urlSegments = subRoutes.map(subRoute => subRoute.path);
    return `/${urlSegments.join('/')}`;
  }
```

When attempting to change the route to a component saved by the "RouteReuseStrategy" but loaded via "LazyLoad," it doesn't update the URL and also doesn't refresh the view (it doesn't switch to the currently displayed component). However, when I do it with a component that hasn't been loaded via "Lazy Load," it works perfectly.

I don't know what else to try, I really appreciate your help.